# TO_DATE function couldn't execute in Sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, to-date

TO_DATE function couldn't prepare statement. Where is mistake in this query?

```
UPDATE Employees SET BirthDate = TO_DATE('01042015233514','DD.Month.YYYY HH:MI:SS'), LastName = 'YURTCU' WHERE FirstName = 'SENEM';
```

Please help me. Thank You!

Comment: Your value `'01042015233514'` does not match your format `'DD.Month.YYYY HH:MI:SS'`. For details please see the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#CDEHIFJA

Comment: I changed to 01.04.2015 23:35:14. But I have same error.

Comment: `04` vs. `Month`, please read the manual

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I see your given input string and date pattern are not matched, for your given strigng (`01042015233514`) you have to use `DDMMYYYYHH24MISS` format to convert it to date:

```
select TO_DATE('01042015233514','DDMMYYYYHH24MISS') from dual
```

*output:*

```
01-APR-15 --(in your default format)
```

Comment: Thank you @Farheg. TO_DATE('01.04.2015 23:35:14', '.....') How should I fill in the balnks?

Comment: You are welcome, it's `'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'`, in your given string the first two digit is for day yes?

Comment: Yes, that is day. And it is running. Thank you!